# Formatting phone numbers in Groovy/Grails

Tags: grails

I have been trying to format phone numbers in a grails app by using the following taglib

```
package rewards

class MasksTagLib {
    static defaultEncodeAs = [taglib:'html']
     //static encodeAsForTags = [tagName: [taglib:'html'], otherTagName:            
    [taglib:'none']]    
  def phone334 = { attrs ->
    String phone = attrs.phone
    def formatted = "("+phone.substring(0,3)+") "+pho ne.substring(3,6)+"-"+phone.substring(6)
    out << formatted
  }
 }
```

In addition I have used the import statement to use the taglib in my views, however the format is not changing the display in the index.gsp for the CustomerController 
This works in the following view, but I can't get it to work elsewhere the view is profile.gsp

```
<%@ page import="rewards.Customer" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'customer.label',           default: 'Customer')}" />
    <title>Customer Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="edit-customer" class="content scaffold-edit" role="main">
        <h1>Customer Profile</h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <g:hasErrors bean="${customerInstance}">
        <ul class="errors" role="alert">
            <g:eachError bean="${customerInstance}" var="error">
            <li <g:if test="${error in   org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
            </g:eachError>
        </ul>
        </g:hasErrors>
        <g:form url="[resource:customerInstance, action:'updateProfile']" method="PUT" >
            <g:hiddenField name="version" value="${customerInstance?.version}" />
            <fieldset class="buttons">
                <g:actionSubmit class="save" action="updateProfile" value="${message(code: 'default.button.update.label', default: 'Update')}" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form">
                <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: customerInstance, field: 'firstName', 'error')} ">
                    <label for="firstName">
                        <g:message code="customer.firstName.label" default="First Name" />

                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="firstName" value="${customerInstance?.firstName}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: customerInstance, field: 'lastName', 'error')} ">
                    <label for="lastName">
                        <g:message code="customer.lastName.label" default="Last Name" />

                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="lastName" value="${customerInstance?.lastName}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: customerInstance, field: 'phone', 'error')} required">
                    <span id="phone-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="customer.phone.label" default="Phone" /></span>
                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="phone-label"><g:phone334 phone="${customerInstance?.phone}"/></span>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: customerInstance, field: 'email', 'error')} ">
                    <label for="email">
                        <g:message code="customer.email.label" default="Email" />

                    </label>
                    <g:textField name="email" value="${customerInstance?.email}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: customerInstance, field: 'totalPoints', 'error')} required">
                    <span id="totalPoints-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="customer.totalPoints.label" default="Total Points" /></span>
                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="totalPoints-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${customerInstance}" field="totalPoints"/></span>

                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </g:form>
    </div>

    <div id="list-award" class="content scaffold-list" role="main">
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <table>
        <thead>
                <tr>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="type" title="${message(code: 'award.type.label', default: 'Type')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="awardDate" title="${message(code: 'award.checkinDate.label', default: 'Award Date')}" />

                    <th><g:message code="award.customer.label" default="Phone" /></th>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="points" title="${message(code: 'award.points.label', default: 'Points')}" />

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${customerInstance.awards}" status="i" var="checkinInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: checkinInstance, field: "type")}</td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: checkinInstance, field: "awardDate")}</td>

                    <td><g:phone334 phone="${customerInstance?.phone}"/></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: checkinInstance, field: "points")}</td>
                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
```

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Here is the Controller. It is called CustomerController.groovy and it is displaying the list using "Index". How can I apply the phone format to this list

```
    package rewards

class CustomerController {
static scaffold = true

def calculationsService

def lookup() {
    // def customerInstance = Customer.list(sort: "lastName", order:       
   "desc", max: 5, offset: 5)
    // dynamic queries
    // def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByLastName("Foster")
    // def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByTotalPoints(5, [sort: "lastName", order: "desc"])
    // def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByPhone(params.id)  // for one row return findBy if rows > 1 only first
    // def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByLastNameLike("H%")  // Case Sensitive
    // def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByLastNameIlike("b%")  // Case Insensitive
    // def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByTotalPointsGreaterThanEquals(3, [sort: "totalPoints"])
    // def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByTotalPointsBetween(2, 4, [sort: "totalPoints"])
    def customerInstance = Customer.findAllByFirstNameIlikeAndTotalPointsGreaterThanEquals("b%", 3)
    [customerInstanceList: customerInstance]
}

def customerLookup(Customer lookupInstance) {
    // Query customer by Phone number - service
    // If no result, - controller
    // create a new customer - service
    // create welcome message - service
    // add award reward - service
    // save customer - service
    // send welcome to kiosk - controller
    // if customer found - controller
    // calculate total ponts - service
    // create welcome message - service
    // add award reward - service
    // save customer - controller
    // send welcome to kiosk - controller
    def (customerInstance, welcomeMessage) = calculationsService.processCheckin(lookupInstance)
    render(view: "checkin", model:[customerInstance: customerInstance, welcomeMessage: welcomeMessage])
}
def index() {
    params.max = 10
    [customerInstanceList: Customer.list(params), customerInstanceCount: Customer.count()]
}

def create() {
    [customerInstance: new Customer()]
}

def save(Customer customerInstance) {
    customerInstance.save()
    redirect(action: "show", id: customerInstance.id)
}

def show(Long id) {
    def customerInstance = Customer.get(id)
    customerInstance = calculationsService.getTotalPoints(customerInstance)
    [customerInstance: customerInstance]
}

def edit(Long id) {
    def customerInstance = Customer.get(id)
    [customerInstance: customerInstance]
}

def update(Long id) {
    def customerInstance = Customer.get(id)
    customerInstance.properties = params
    customerInstance.save()
    redirect(action: "show", id: customerInstance.id)
}

def delete(Long id) {
    def customerInstance = Customer.get(id)
    customerInstance.delete()
    redirect(action: "index")
}

def profile() {
    def customerInstance = Customer.findByPhone(params.id)
    [customerInstance: customerInstance]
}

def updateProfile(Customer customerInstance) {
    customerInstance.save()
    render(view: "profile", model:[customerInstance: customerInstance])
}

def checkin() {}

}
```

[Customer List Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJGnu.jpg)

Comment: can we see the gsp where it doesn't work? also I guess that's a typo in the taglib above where there's a space in the word pho ne?

Comment: "In addition I have used the import statement to use the taglib in my views" - You don't need import statements in order to use taglibs in views.

Comment: I can show you the Controller. It is using index to display the customer list. How do I apply the format to the display

Comment: So the gsp above is `profile.gsp` which works okay as you've added the taglib call, but for index you're using scaffolding still for the gsp?

Comment: The space in the taglib file is as a result of my copying the code in the code block

Comment: the first display for the controller which displays the list is using scaffolding so in order to change this I have to customize instead of using scaffolding?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize your index view, your best bet in this case is to stop using the scaffolded page, yes.  (There are alternatives, but they're overly complicated for this situation, and don't offer you nearly as much control over the resulting view.)

In general, it's not a good idea long-term to have half-scaffolded content.  By this, I mean either scaffolded controllers, or scaffolded views, but not the other side.  Long term, one or the other is likely to change, and your pages will break.

Comment: A few other comments while I'm looking at your code: look at <g:renderErrors /> as an alternative to how you're rendering errors now, since you may find it cleaner.  You can remove the taglib import.  Quite a few of your controller actions do appear to still be standard scaffolded ones, so if you're going to leave the views alone too, you could probably just take those out and let the scaffolding do the work, but I know details often get taken out for posting here so that may not be "real".  Good luck with getting everything working!